# Toggle Video on Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, video, toggle

I'm trying to get a button when clicked to swap out a video for another which is autoplaying and looping.

Really cant seam to figure this one out, any help would be great!

Heres my code,

```
 <div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Live Fire</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <button>Clicky</button>
        <br>
        <video id="container" width="600" height="400" src="video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>

    </div><!-- /content    -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar">
    <a href="#" data-icon="plus">Add</a>

</div>
</div><!-- /page -->
<script>
    $('button').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this).data('toggle') ? '<video id="container" width="600" height="400" src="video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>' : '<video id="container" width="600" height="400" src="video/3.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>';
    $(this).data('toggle', !$(this).data('toggle'));
    $('#container').html($el);
});
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your video htmlstring isn't wrapped in quotes... that HAS to be throwing an obvious javascript error.

Comment: o yeah whoops, just updated it, i'm still learning jquery :(

Comment: That still won't work, you're inner quotes are breaking your outer quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`toggle()` no longer works like you think it does after jQuery 1.9, it has been replaced with an animation method.

Here is one way you could do it with jQuery 1.9.1:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this).data('toggle') ? VIDEO_1 : VIDEO_2;
    $(this).data('toggle', !$(this).data('toggle'));
    $('#container').html($el);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K8Tsu/1/)

Comment: Hey Neil S, this is great! thanks allot you have saved my bacon! i'm trying to make it work with local videos but it doesent seam to toggle ,   heres my code, <script>
    $('button').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this).data('toggle') ? '<video width="600" height="400" src="video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>' : '<video width="600" height="400" src="video/3.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>';
    $(this).data('toggle', !$(this).data('toggle'));
    $('#container').html($el);
});
    </script>

Comment: If you are going to use html5 video elements, you might want to have the container element be a blank video element, and then have jquery insert source elements in the container. Using my code above, if #container was a reference to a video element as such: <video id="container" width="600" height="400"></video>, and VIDEO_1 would be something like <source src="video/1.mp4" type="video.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">

Comment: i've update the code, the video plays and loops but the button doesnt do anything now :(

Comment: again, you should probably try what I suggested in the comment above. http://jsfiddle.net/Y4VA9/

Comment: You also should wrap your jQuery binding in a ready function, so that you ensure the DOM is ready before you bind. `$(function(){ //your binds here });`